# How can I lock Mail/Contact/Calendars in an iPad?

Tags: ipad, email

All members of my family use the iPad primarily for browsing the Web or playing games.  It is basically a living room computer. But I use it also for my e-mail.

I know The iPad can be locked with a passcode as a whole (which I don't really need, because anyone who makes it to my living room is welcome to use it), but I would like to lock only the Mail app.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jailbreaking, I believe your options are the use of apps that provide this kind of lock functionality built-in, unless Apple decide to implement some kind of [multiple user support](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/05/07/apple_says_lack_of_multi_user_support_on_ipad_is_a_known_issue_being_investigated.html) in future iOS versions for devices like the iPad.

I've previously come across [Secure Gmail](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/secure-gmail/id496041864?mt=8) or [Secure Webmail](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/secure-webmail/id510417578?mt=8) (there may well be others) which provide passcode protection schemes when starting and, judging by the screenshots, appear to be frontends to the relevant webmail pages (as opposed to a native application like the Apple Mail app). I've not used either, but they may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you've jailbroken your iPad. And these days, [it's still very easy to do so](http://jailbreakipadhelp.com/).
If you've jailbroken your iPad, you have some solutions:

- Lockdown Pro - BigBoss repo - $2.99
- FolderLock - BigBoss repo - $1.59
- Locktopus - BigBoss repo - $2.00

My favorite is Locktopus, because it's the app you can customize most.

[The Daily Buggle](http://www.thedailybuggle.com/password-protect-apps-iphone-ipod-touch-ipad/) wrote an excellent post about this topic (and how to use those apps) and they prefer Locktopus too :)

Answer (score -2):

One of the best password/passcode protected e-mail apps is CloudMagic.  It works on non-jailbroken iOS devices, has received great reviews and I have used it for years.   :)

Comment: Hi there - welcome to Ask Different! I think your question might be getting downvoted because it kind of looks like no context spam - would you be willing to expand your answer a bit?